# asp.net mvc datatable

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

How can I pass datatable to the mvc view

How would I iterate over it in the view

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    return View(dt);
}
```

In your View:
Just make your model of type DataTable

```
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<System.Data.DataTable>"
```

To iterate over it:

```
 <% foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in Model.Rows) { %>

        <%= row["column"].ToString(); %>   

 <%}%>
```