# pass datatable to the mvc view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I was reading: [asp.net mvc datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2794831)

But I have give a compilation error:

CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DataTable' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

add a reference at the top of the class.

```
using System.Data;
```